# What's a good prior distribution for degrees of freedom in a t distribution?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, modeling, prior

I want to use a t distribution to model short interval asset returns in a bayesian model. I'd like to estimate both the degrees of freedom (along with other parameters in my model) for the distribution.  I know that asset returns are quite non-normal, but I don't know too much beyond that.

What is an appropriate, mildly informative prior distribution for the degrees of freedom in such a model?

Comment: A t distribution might not be a good choice, because it is symmetric whereas asset returns tend to have strong skew.  At a minimum, consider modeling the *logarithms* of the returns rather than the returns themselves.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point, I was thinking about that in the back of my mind, but this question is still of interest to me.

Comment: Do you have a truly *huge* amount of data? I think it's more common even in Bayesian modelling to fix the df and try different values as a sensitivity analysis.

Comment: Here's an article that might help. http://www.portfolioprobe.com/2011/01/12/the-number-1-novice-quant-mistake/

Comment: I do have a pretty large quantity of data, but it may be that this is the best approach. Submit as an answer and I'll vote you up and accept if no one provides a better solution.

Comment: note that using t-distribution for GARCH returns is quite popular in financial econometrics. So the question is pretty valid and does not imply that the link applies to the poster.

Comment: @mpiktas I am not sure, but bill_080's point might have been that at the very beginning of the article they use n = 6 for their t-distribution. It can be useful to know what people consider reasonable values.

Comment: @John, you are correct, n=6 was my point.   I tried several schemes that you might use in fitting n for your data and a t distribution (using fitdist from package fitdistrplus), but I couldn't configure a way that I thought was worth posting.

Comment: I would try using the Laplace distribution for asset returns, also called the "double exponential" is stats-world, and "variance-gamma" in Finance world.

Comment: This [link](http://andrewgelman.com/2015/05/17/do-we-have-any-recommendations-for-priors-for-student_ts-degrees-of-freedom-parameter/) might be helpfule for you, which has many informative comments and references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On page 372 of [ARM](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/), Gelman and Hill mention using a uniform distribution on the inverse of DF between 1/DF = .5 and 1/DF = 0.

Specifically, in BUGS, they use:

```
nu.y <- 1/nu.inv.y 
nu.inv.y ~ dunif(0,.5)
```

Comment: May I ask, in PyMC3, is the `nu` parameter for the StudentsT distribution the degrees of freedom, or its inverse?

Comment: My bad, I didn't read the docs. It's an integer.

Answer (score 5):

[ARM](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/) (as referenced by John Salvatier in his answer) was originally published in 2006. Since then, there has been advocation of using a $ \nu \sim \text{Gamma}(2, 0.1)$ prior. This prior was proposed by Juárez and Steel (2010) in their paper [Model-based clustering of non-Gaussian panel data based on skew-t distributions](https://doi.org/10.1198/jbes.2009.07145).

Gelman made the following post in 2015: [“Do we have any recommendations for priors for student_t’s degrees of freedom parameter?”](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2015/05/17/do-we-have-any-recommendations-for-priors-for-student_ts-degrees-of-freedom-parameter/), which discusses this topic in more detail (as well as the penalised complexity prior proposed by Simpson et al (2014)).